# batch command copy file whose name is part of a directory

Tags: batch-file

The files names are a part of the name of the directories, which can be at the end or at the beginning of the directory. For example:

```
pic.jpg into directory \newyork-pic
flower.gif into directory \italy-flower
computer.jpg into directory \computer-informatic
etc
```

Do you know a way to do that with a batch file?

Comment: Your question is unclear... do you want to copy the file into the directory? or out of the directory? or only certain files?  Please clarify your question.

Comment: do you have list of the target directories? Or they are sub-directories of a known directory?

Comment: Please also understand that the site members are not supposed to write your scripts for you. You are supposed to perform the work yourself and ask for help where you are stuck.

Comment: hello i have this which copy files in a directory with the exact same name for %%i in (*) do move "%%i" "%%~ni" ...for abelenky i want to copy the files into directories i have but my directories have only a part of the file name

Comment: Please note that https://stackoverflow.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a piece of example code which should get you most of the way there:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Tokens=1-2 Delims=-" %%A In (
    'Dir/B/AD-S "*-*"^|FindStr/BRIE "[^-]*[-][^-]*"') Do For %%C In (
    "%%A" "%%B") Do If Exist "%%~C.*" Move /-Y "%%~C.*" "%%A-%%B"
```

Comment: I'm glad it satisfied your requirements. _It would help both future searches and motivate future responders were you to mark the answer as correct_.